# What does shell do when we redirect using "<"?

Tags: linux, shell, process

Say I have a program called fstatcheck. It takes one argument from the command line and treat it as file descriptor. It checks the stat information of the file pointed by the file descriptor.

For example:

```
$./fstatcheck 1
l = 1
type: other, read: yes
```

Another example:

```
$./fstatcheck 3 < foobar.txt 
l = 3
Fstat error: Bad file descriptor
```

Questions:

1. What is the shell doing in the second example?
   I can guess that it takes 3 as a file descriptor and starts to analyze the stat, but descriptor 3 is not open. But how does shell treat the redirection?

   I assume the shell performs the following algorithm:

   ```
   if (fork() == 0) {
     // What does the shell do here?
     execve("fstatcheck", argv, envp);
   }
   ```
2. Is there any way I can create a file descriptor 3 and let it connect to an open file table which points to foobar.txt file stat by just using the shell command (instead of using C code)?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's find out with `strace`:

```
$ strace sh -c 'cat < /dev/null'
[...]
open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY)             = 3
fcntl(0, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 10
close(0)                                = 0
fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
dup2(3, 0)                              = 0
close(3)                                = 0
[...]
execve("/bin/cat", ["cat"], [/* 28 vars */]) = 0
[...]
```

So in your code, the relevant parts would be:

```
if (fork() == 0) {
  int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);  // Open the file
  close(0);                           // Close old stdin
  dup2(fd, 0);                        // Copy fd as new stdin
  close(fd);                          // Close the original fd
  execve("fstatcheck", argv, envp);   // Execute
}
```

As for opening another fd, absolutely:

```
myprogram 3< file
```

This will open `file` for reading on fd 3 for the program. `<` alone is a synonym for `0<`.